# Mono Develop - Installing Linux FlatPak package

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

I am trying to set up Mono on a Ubuntu VM. The Mono part of the process goes along fine. But when I enter the command to download Mono Develop IDE, the process hangs at "Starting download" phase without the download every actually starting. This is the last output I see.

Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks for any help.

```
xxxxx@xxxxx-VirtualBox:~$ sudo flatpak install --user --from https://download.mono-project.com/repo/monodevelop.flatpakref
[sudo] password for xxxxx: 
Installing: com.xamarin.MonoDevelop/x86_64/stable
Required runtime for com.xamarin.MonoDevelop/x86_64/stable (org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/1.4) is not installed, searching...
Found in remote gnome, do you want to install it? [y/n]: y
Installing: org.freedesktop.Platform/x86_64/1.4 from gnome

Receiving delta parts: 0/8 -/s 0 bytes/117.3 MB - remaining
```

To install Mono, I am following the instructions from here: http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin

To install Mono Develop, I am following the instructions from here: http://www.monodevelop.com/download/

Comment: If there's no special reason to choose flatpak, just install the community package.